# Find duplicate elements in list of dictionaries & output values in rang

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a list of dictionaries like this.

```
x=({'apple': 5, 'mango': 3,'banana': 2}, {'apple': 6, 'mango': 1})
```

I want to find the find the duplicate elements in sub-dictionary & range values with key. Example.

**Expected outputs**

```
{'apple': [5, 6], 'mango': [1, 3], 'banana': [2, 2]}
```

After applying some basics. I've worked on this problem as follows.

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for i, d in enumerate(x):
    result[frozenset(d.items())].append(i)
print(result)
```

Output I got.

```
defaultdict(list,
            {frozenset({('apple', 5), ('banana', 2), ('mango', 3)}): [0],
             frozenset({('apple', 6), ('mango', 1)}): [1]})
```

As I mentioned before my expected output should be list of duplicate key range values. Can you guys help me what are the steps/Logic should I apply so that I can get expected outputs as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) use `dict.setdefault` to combine the list of dictionaries

(ii) sort the values of the dictionary from (i) to obtain the range values

```
out = {}
for d in x:
    for k,v in d.items():
        out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

for k,v in out.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        v.sort()
        out[k] = [v[0], v[-1]]
    else:
        out[k] = [v[0], v[0]]
```

Output:

```
{'apple': [5, 6], 'mango': [1, 3], 'banana': [2, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given `tuple`. But, Consider that your source data is a `list`.

```
x=[{'apple': 5, 'mango': 3,'banana': 2}, {'apple': 6, 'mango': 1}]

sourceDict = {}
for i in x:
    for key,value in i.items():
        if not key in sourceDict:
            sourceDict.update({key:[value]})
        else:
            sourceDict[key].append(value)
```

`sourceDict` output:

```
{'apple': [5, 6], 'mango': [3, 1], 'banana': [2]}
```

Incase if you want them to sorted,

```
for i,j in sourceDict.items():
    sourceDict[i] = sorted(j)
```

which gives,

```
{'apple': [5, 6], 'mango': [1, 3], 'banana': [2]}
```